# How to show JSON object by using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, requirejs, orientdb

I'm creating a treeview menu using angularJS. Is there any way to get this results? I'm using a controller to get this ($scope.results). and I put the JSON result set and the controller..

```
<ul>
   <li class="folder"><span>Pages</span>
     <ul>
       <li class="file"><span>page1</span></li>
       <li class="file"><span>page2</span></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="folder"><span>TestSuites</span>
     <ul>
       <li class="file"><span>TestSuites1</span></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JSON..

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:1",
            "@version": 0,
            "name": "pg3"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:2",
            "@version": 0,
            "name": "pg3"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:3",
            "@version": 0,
            "name": "pg3"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.023 sec. Returned 3 record(s)"
}
```

Controller..

```
vController.controller('v-PagesController', [
                '$scope',
                '$q',
                'vRESTService',
                function($scope, $q, vRESTService) {

                    vRESTService.getPages().then(
                            function(results) {
                                $scope.results = results;
                                console.log(results);
                                //console.log(results);
                              //  console.log(res);
    //;;
                        }, function() {
                                console.log(Error);
                            });
                }               

        ]);
```

Comment: Post the JSON object you want to show

Comment: I'm using oreintDB here. this is the result set that in the console. [Object { @type="d", @rid="#-2:1", @version=0, more...}, Object { @type="d", @rid="#-2:2", @version=0, more...}, Object { @type="d", @rid="#-2:3", @version=0, more...}]

Comment: The result is coming until to the controller, but I can't show it in the html. and this is the code I used in html....    
<li class="closed" ng-controller="vtaf-PagesController" ><span class="folder">Pages</span>
   <ul>   
    <li ng-model="selectedExPlan" data-tree-model="result in results">{{resultl.name}}</li>
   </ul>
  </li>

Comment: Can you show the json that comes back in the network tab of the browser?

Comment: Try this one http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

Comment: {
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:1",
            "@version": 0,
            "name": "pg3"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:2",
            "@version": 0,
            "name": "pg3"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:3",
            "@version": 0,
            "name": "pg3"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.023 sec. Returned 3 record(s)"
}

Comment: Where are the test suits in your result?

Comment: Still didn't code that part. First of all I need to add the pages. I need get loaded all the pages in that html under the <ul>. I edited that code and put the json there.

Comment: I'm guessing you are expecting 'pg3' to appear instead of 'page3' as indicated in the question

Comment: yes I'm expecting pg3..

Answer (score 0):

I've only presented the pages part as you have said that the json doesn't contain the testsuites yet:

Modify your controller to assign results to a scope property:

```
vRESTService.getPages().then(
   function(results) {
      console.log(results);
      $scope.results = results;             
   }
```

Then your view should be as follows:

```
<ul>
   <li class="folder"><span>Pages</span>
     <ul>
       <li class="file" ng-repeat="page in results.result"><span>{{page.name}}</span></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/mKLTxwskjPECkQUCsV05?p=preview

I'd recommend you change your json to have a pages property and a testSuites property:

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:1",
        "@version": 0,
        "name": "pg3"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:2",
        "@version": 0,
        "name": "pg3"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:3",
        "@version": 0,
        "name": "pg3"
    }
  ],
  "testSuites": [
    {
        "name": "TestSuites1"
    }
  ],
  "notification": "Query executed in 0.023 sec. Returned 3 record(s)"
}
```

And then your view would be:

```
<ul>
   <li class="folder"><span>Pages</span>
     <ul>
       <li class="file" ng-repeat="page in results.pages"><span>{{page.name}}</span></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="folder"><span>TestSuites</span>
     <ul>
       <li class="file" ng-repeat="testSuite in results.testSuites"><span>{{testSuite.name}}</span></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dL2OGTkiEOSzmK0O1pux?p=preview

Comment: Hey still not working :( is there any way to check if the results is coming to the HTML file?

Comment: Are you assigning the json to $scope.results? Use the developer tools to check the network tab to verify the json. Also check the console for any errors

Comment: hey added the controller also. can you check the code again?

Comment: So you need to assign $scope.results like: function(results) {$scope.results = results;}

Comment: Hey I added that part, but still not working. and I edited here also.. and I checked adding the JSON result to that $scope.results = (json result.....) without getting from the DB (hardcodded). but it's also not working.

Comment: What's the result of console.log(results); Can you please try to post a plunkr of it not working.

Comment: this is that result.. I think it's ok.. 
[Object { @type="d", @rid="#-2:1", @version=0, more...}, Object { @type="d", @rid="#-2:2", @version=0, more...}, Object { @type="d", @rid="#-2:3", @version=0, more...}]

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use $http.get 
Js file 
$http.get('.json file ').success(function(data) {
    $scope.name = name;
}

HTML File 
<table> <tr ng-repeat= "x in y"> <td>{{x.Name }}</td> </tr> </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS provides $http.get method to fetch JSON file. Once you fetch the data in response store it into a $scope object inside your controller. Then use ng-repeat to bind that data. Look at the example here http://jharaphula.com/how-to-display-json-data-in-a-table-using-angularjs